# Is it possible to get information like the reactions or likes from a certain post in a page that isn´t mine from facebook graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I´m doing a special project where I need to get info like comments, likes and reactions from a page´s post in facebook but i don´t know if it´s possible or not. I can get the info from my own page with Facebook Graph API but in the final result I need to get the info from another page that isn´t mine

I´ve been searching on google and stackoverflow if it´s possible to get what I need but it seems that the answers are from a long time ago and I want to know if it´s possible to do it now after the news in the past year about Cambridge Analytica doing nasty things with the data

Comment: I have already done this with graph api but not sure that is it possible with the newer version

Answer (score 0):

No, even with Page Public Content Access features you cannot get a public page's post likes or reactions, but only comments (but w/o the actual user details, so only the comment text and date/time).